# Spring Boot control target JAR file name

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

My Spring Boot project has build description:

```
<build>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.app.MainClass</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

I want my JAR file name to be `app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` in one branch and `1.0-RELEASE.jar` in another, controlled by Jenkins (using some kind of mvn settings or JVM argument such as -D..

Can I do this?

Comment: in your second branch, the `pom.xml` would already have `version` as `1.0-RELEASE`? If the case, then everything would already work out-of-the-box, but the question is: how are you handling releases and branching? Are you using `maven-release-plugin`? which version control are you using and which branching strategy (i.e. git, gitflow)?

Comment: I don't see any special settings in the spring boot parent. So the jar name is derived from build.finalName: <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>. You could reconfigure that adding a branch property into it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can specify the artefact-name with the maven boot plugin:

In this case, it will be `NewJarName.jar`

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>repackage</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>NewJarName</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: You forgot to add the `/` to the second `<finalName>`.

Answer (score 51):

So simple, In one branch, you have `pom.xml` with

```
<build>
  <finalName>app-1.0-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
</build>
```

In other branch, you have `pom.xml` with

```
<build>
  <finalName>1.0-RELEASE</finalName>
</build>
```

Answer (score 22):

You can propagate the version of the project to your build name like this:

```
<build>
    <finalName>app-${project.version}</finalName>
</build>
```

or the version of your parent project if you have one:

```
<build>
    <finalName>app-${parent.version}</finalName>
</build>
```

Then you would keep track of you project version rather than the build name.

**However**, note that managing the build verson in SCM using branches is a pain in the neck and error prone. It is rather recommanded that your code repository woud be agnostic of your build version.

A possible alternative would be to use some release management tool, like `maven release plugin`, or even more simple `maven version`.

**Example:**

Here I'll give and example using `maven verion`.

Say you're using SCM tool (it could be `git`) and a build factory (like `Jenkins` or any other tool). Say you have a job to build and deploy *snapshots* and another one for *releases*.

In the *snapshot* job, you can set-up a pre-build task with the following maven target:

```
versions:set -DnewVersion=app-1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

and the following in the *release* job:

```
versions:set -DnewVersion=app-1.0-RELEASE
```

Now doing this is OK, because you are only doing it locally and never have to manage the build version in your code.

**Now**, you can tag your (release) version after having applied `maven version` and build successfuly (hopefuly including unit, integration and functional tests). This way you may keep track exactly of the code that has been deployed on each release.

**Tip!!** Space is money! Do yourself a favour: clean your snapshot repository regularly. Creating a job that does so every once in a while shouldn't be to difficult.